# how to hide x and y values of matplotlib figure while mouse hover

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

as you know in `matplotlib` plots, shows a value for x and a value for y while hovering the mouse on plots (the red border in the picture below).
is there any way to hide them and make `plt` not to show them at all? so the figure do not show the values after mouse hover on plot.

```
# just a simple code
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reassign the callback function that displays the coordinates (`ax.format_coord`) to a function that outputs an empty string:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.scatter(np.random.rand(20), np.random.rand(20))
plt.gca().format_coord = lambda x,y: ""
plt.show()
```

[This example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/image_zcoord.html) uses the function to show pixel values.